# SFMC retrieve data from data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

2 questions:
1. I need to retrieve data from DE with SOAP API.
I'm trying to use postman with get and the wsdl end point (do I need the SOAP instead?)
this is the call Im using:

```
    <Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
     <Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <UsernameToken wsu:Id="token" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     </UsernameToken>
     </Security>
     </Header>
     <Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <RetrieveRequest>
      <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[IL_DE_Enroll]</ObjectType>
        <Properties>encrypt_Key</Properties>
        <Properties>Phone_Number</Properties>
        <Properties>Email_Address</Properties>
        <Properties>Last_Name</Properties>
        <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
        <Retrieves />
        <Options>
           <SaveOptions />
           <IncludeObjects>true</IncludeObjects>
        </Options>
     </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

Im getting 200 OK but it seems there is an error. what is wrong with the code?

2. I need to get email opens, clicks and bounce data but can not find any SOAP call that I can use. I know there is tracking data export but don't want to use the SFTP.
   Is there a way to retrieve this data without using customerID/ email filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're providing the correct External Key for your data extension, not the name of the data extension.Your request body would be like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <fueloauth>{{_token}}</fueloauth>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[IL_DE_Enroll]</ObjectType>
                <Properties>encrypt_Key</Properties>
                <Properties>Phone_Number</Properties>
                <Properties>Email_Address</Properties>
                <Properties>Last_Name</Properties>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'd **STRONGLY** recommend you reconsider your preference for using SOAP over SFTP for this, but you're interested in the [SentEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sentevent.htm), [OpenEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/openevent.htm), [ClickEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/clickevent.htm) and [BounceEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/bounceevent.htm) (etc) SOAP objects. Review [Retrieve SentEvent Details for Job](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieve_sentevent_details_for_job.htm) and [Retrieving Bounce Event Details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_bounce_event_details.htm) for implementation examples. Also review [Retrieve All Records Since Last Batch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_all_records_since_last_batch.htm) to understand how you can "efficiently" access tracking events without having to store high watermarks locally.